# How to pass on optional arguments, but with different default values?

Tags: optional-arguments

### Main question

I want to define a function `g` that calls a function `f`. `g` has optional arguments, some of which it passes on to `f` when `f` is called. However, I want the default values of the options for `g`to be different than the defaults  `f`. How do I define `g`efficiently?

### Example

Suppose I have a function `f[x]` with optional arguments `a`, `b`, and `c` defined below:

```
Options[f] = {a->y,b->z,c->w};
f[x_,OptionsPattern[]]:={x,OptionValue[a],OptionValue[b],OptionValue[c]}
```

Evaluating `f[x]` yields `{x, y, z, w}`. Evaluating `f[x,a->0,c-> 2]` yields `{x, 0, z, 2}` etc.

Now I want a function `g[x]` whose output is `f[2 x]`. Additionally, I want  `g`to have the same optional arguments as `f`, but with different default values:`{a->2,b->4,c->6}`. How do I define `g` efficiently?

The code below doesn't work:

```
Options[g] = {a->2,b->4,c->6}
g[x_,opts:OptionsPattern[]]:= f[2 x,opts]
```

Evaluating `g[x]` yields `{2 x, y, z, w}`. Evaluating `g[x, b -> 10]` yields `{2 x, y, 10, w}`. Clearly, the default options for `g` are effectively the default options for `f`, which is not what we wanted.

The code below *does* work, but is clunky:

```
Options[g] = {a -> 2, b -> 4, c -> 6};
g[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 f[2 x, Sequence @@ ((#[[1]] -> OptionValue[#[[1]]]) & /@ Options[f])]
```

Now, Evaluating`g[x]` yields `{2 x, 2, 4, 6}`, and `g[x,b->10]` yields  `{2 x, 2, 10, 6}` as desired. But it feels like there must be a simpler way to write the code for `g`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `g[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := f[2 x, opts, Options[g]]`? `OptionsPattern` is fairly robust for catenating options and lists of options. (First occurrence takes precedence over later ones.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh, I had no idea it was that simple. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!